# On Linux fonts shows thicker

Tags: html, css, linux, fonts

I have a little problem with my website on Linux. Fonts on Linux I see thicker, like Thin font. Even on Apple computers fonts showing nice. Im using a Google Roboto font. Below is example of fonts

This is my CSS how im using `font-face`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Light';
    src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Regular';
    src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto Medium';
    src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal
}
```

**Windows**

[image]

**Linux**

[image]

*Exchange is highlighted with white color **on LINUX***

Any solutions?

Comment: It's actually a problem with Windows for not making fonts look anti-aliased. `:(` Check in Mac too. Looks like Linux. `<3`

Comment: @PraveenKumar quote from my problem "Even on Apple computers fonts showing nice." For Windows and Apple i dont have a problem with this font. Only on Linux

Comment: It depends on browser. Mozilla uses freetype library for rendering fonts while chrome has its own fontrendering engine.

Comment: @DanielsJirgensons That's crazy... Yup... It is something to do with the Font Renderer...

Comment: In Linux, there are settings to the font renderer. See [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/get-great-looking-fonts-in-kde/) for KDE; not sure about other environments.